# Outlook on windows resizes images on emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, outlook, amazon-ses

I have the following function to send emails:

```
import logging
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

import boto3


def send_email(body, subject, recipients, region_name='us-east-1',
               sender='default@sender.com', attachments=False):
    logging.info('Generating email from {} to {} about {}'.format(sender,
                                                                  str(recipients),
                                                                  subject))

    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['Subject'] = subject
    message['From'] = sender
    message['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)

    logging.info('Adding attachments...')

    if attachments:
        for attachment in attachments:
            logging.info('Adding ' + attachment)

            f = open(os.path.normpath(attachment), 'rb')
            a = MIMEApplication(f.read())
            f.close()
            a.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                         filename=os.path.basename(attachment))
            message.attach(a)

            logging.info('Attachment added!')

    else:
        logging.info('No attachments found!')

    logging.info('Adding body...')

    part = MIMEText(body, 'html')
    message.attach(part)

    client = boto3.client('ses', region_name=region_name)

    logging.info('Sending...')
    client.send_raw_email(
        Source=message['From'],
        Destinations=recipients,
        RawMessage={
            'Data': message.as_string()
        }
    )

    logging.info('Sent!')
```

This works like a charm and i use it with a variety of use cases. One of the use cases i have is to send an image in the body of the email. When that happens, I do something like this:

```
send_email('''<img src="cid:{}" width={} height={}>'''.format(final_image_name,
                                                                  width_of_new_image,
                                                                  height_of_new_image),
               'Email with body image', recipients,
               attachments=['/tmp/{}'.format(final_image_name), ])
```

And it works. All perfect when open the email in an iPad, iPhone, Mail app and Outlook for Mac. However... all hell breaks loose when my co-workers open them in Outlook in Windows. Some see very tiny images, some get distorted images, some have to make 250% some to see the email in readable size. Since this works on everything else with the exception of Outlook on Windows, I have to assume that the problem is there. Is there a way for me to correct this in code? Is there an outlook setting to prevent this? Most of my co-workers use Windows so I need a little help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Outlook, so I can't reproduce the problem.

Try adding quotes and `px` with the width and height attributes, like so:

```py
send_email('''<img src="cid:{}" width="{}px" height="{}px">'''.format(final_image_name,
                                                                  width_of_new_image,
                                                                  height_of_new_image),
               'Email with body image', recipients,
               attachments=['/tmp/{}'.format(final_image_name), ])
```

Maybe Outlook is scaling down the image so it fits in the window?

Try wrapping the `img` tag in a `div` and force a minimum width/height.

```py
html_str = f'''<div style="width: 100%; min-width: {width_of_new_image}px; height: 100%; min-height: {height_of_new_image}px;"><img src="cid:{final_image_name}" width="{width_of_new_image}px" height="{height_of_new_image}px"></div>'''
send_email(html_str, 'Email with body image', recipients, attachments=['/tmp/{}'.format(final_image_name), ])
```

The above code should produce something like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-width: 800px; height: 100%; min-height: 600px;"><img src="cid:imagename" width="800px" height="600px"></div>
```